# How to get anchor tags centered within a DIV?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(245, 225, 130);">
  <div style="margin: 5px;">
    <a href="#link">#down2#</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's the code i'm currently trying. It's a bit of a mess at the moment. But basically, I'm trying to make it so I have  a 25px x 25px div which stores the numbers of the pages in those boxes (part of a paginator), I want it so the number 1 is just as centered as the number 100. At the moment the number1 makes the box shrink in the method i have to center it but when I create a defined box size it just takes the number out alignment. Somebody know a quick fix to centering elements within divs?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a style="display:block; text-align:center"; href="#link#">#down2#</a>
```

Also, lowercase your elements, it's not the nineties anymore

Comment: It's my personal choice how i decide to use my markup. I prefer it this way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @LeeB - Just FYI. Using all caps markup won't validate in all doctypes. Technically it will still work. However if you are checking to see if your code is valid, you might get validation errors. I am almost certain it won't validate using 1.0. However you can always check it here. http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck - Not sure how many doctypes you intend to be using, and I'm not sure your validate statement is correct because browsers themselves uppercase tag names, but you should only be using a strict doctype as any other kind is for deprecated markup and you shouldn't be using deprecated markup. Since you mention '1.0' then I'm assuming you mean XHTML but I doubt he, or you, are serving XHTML as application/xml+xhtml and you're just using 'tag soup' anyway. But this is far too long for a comment.

Comment: XHTML is strictly lowercase. HTML5 encourages lowercase.
http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#tags

Answer (score 1):

With the current text your Div is to small. If just using the number "1" for example you will get what you are looking for.

```
<DIV style="border: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0); height: 30px;width:30px;  background: RGB(245, 225, 130);">
  <DIV style="margin: 5px;">
    <A href="#link#">1</A>
  </DIV>
</DIV>

a {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MD2V6/

**EDIT: Here is a cleaner example.**

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#link#">1</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0); 
    height: 30px;
    width:30px;
    background: RGB(245, 225, 130);
}
a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MD2V6/2/

Comment: your answer worked so i will mark it up + as correct. However, i stated in my post i want a square box so to do that i need to declare the height + width unless i am making a schoolboy error.

Comment: @LeeB - Sorry I missed that at first. The problem right now is that your text is actually longer than its container. So the only way to fix it is to either hide overflow, change the width, or use shorter content.